# Visual Studio 2013 Round-Tripping

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to migrate a Visual Studio 2010 Solution so that I can work with Visual Studio 2013.
If I understand it right, due to the round-tripping feature of Visual Studio 2013,
there is no reason to convert the solution!? I can just open my old solution with 
Visual Studio 2013 and can just work with it.
Is that right? Or is there a good reason or need to do a conversion to a 
Visual Studio 2013 solution.

Or better: Is there any good reason to not stick with the old Visual Studio 2010 solution?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?  Takes 5 minutes, now you got a fact instead of a guess.

Comment: I already tried it with a small test solution and it works all as expected. But I'm not sure if there are any issues if I use a more complex project. Also I'm not sure if I get all the benefits from Visual Studio 2013 if I stick with my Visual Studio 2010 solution. So the main question should be, is there any reason to not stick with the old Visual Studio 2010 solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 can open a `sln` file created by Visual Studio 2010.  However, Visual Studio 2010 can not open a `sln` file created by Visual Studio 2013.

The easiest way to see this is to open the `sln` file in a text editor and look at the first 2 lines:

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
 # Visual Studio 2012
```

Visual Studio has a version setting in the header (this example is from VS 2012).  An older version of the tool wont open the file.

Beyond that there aren't really any big differences in the file.  There are certain project types (ie `Project("{guid}")` that aren't supported in older version of Visual Studio.  For example a Visual Studio 2013 SDK project can only be opened with Visual Studio 2013.

To wrap up, if you have an existing Visual Studio 2010 sln file, there isn't really any need to change it.  If you plan on opening it again in VS2010 then make sure you don't change it.  Otherwise I wouldn't worry about it and just let VS do whatever makes VS happy.